# Dice roll game variables are undefined for for some reason

Tags: javascript

I have create a dice rolling game. An array images are used for the dices. The two dice on the page represent play 1 and play 2. The play with the highest dice value is the winner. Dices that are display on the page should start out with the same dice value until user refresh the page. When the user refresh page, dices will appear with new random dice value. A message will display above dice saying if player one or two is the winner. However, before the game is played,  A message saying  the GAME IS A DRAW appear. Why is my highestDiceRoll and winner variables are undefined?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var highestDiceRoll = 0;
var winner;
 function rollDice () {
 player1 = ['<img src="images/dice1.png" alt="Italian Trulli">',
 '<img src="images/dice2.png" alt="Italian Trulli">',
 '<img src="images/dice3.png" alt="Italian Trulli">',
 '<img src="images/dice4.png" alt="Italian Trulli">',
 '<img src="images/dice5.png" alt="Italian Trulli">',
 '<img src="images/dice6.png" alt="Italian Trulli">'];

 player2 = ['<img src="images/dice1.png" alt="Italian Trulli">',
 '<img src="images/dice2.png" alt="Italian Trulli">',
 '<img src="images/dice3.png" alt="Italian Trulli">',
 '<img src="images/dice4.png" alt="Italian Trulli">',
 '<img src="images/dice5.png" alt="Italian Trulli">',
 '<img src="images/dice6.png" alt="Italian Trulli">'];

var randPlayer1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * player1.length);
var randPlayer2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * player2.length);

 var diceRolls = player1[randPlayer1] + " " + player2[randPlayer2];

 if (player1 > player2) {

    highestDiceRoll = player1;
    winner = "Player 1";
  } else if (player2 > player1) {
    highestDiceRoll = player2;
    winner = "Player 2";
  } else {
    winner = "GAME IS A DRAW";
  }

document.write("The winner is "  + winner + "<br />");
   return diceRolls; //return to display dice on page



}

 document.write(rollDice());

</script>
```

Comment: `player1 > player2` makes no sense since those are two arrays of images.

Comment: Replace `player1` and `player2` in the if-else part with `randPlayer1` and `randPlayer2`

Comment: Declare variables inside function too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are comparing two arrays `player1` and `player2`. You should compare the random values `randPlayer1` and `randPlayer2`.

```js
var highestDiceRoll = 0;
var winner;
 function rollDice () {
 let player1 = ['<img src="images/dice1.png" alt="Italian Trulli">',
 '<img src="images/dice2.png" alt="Italian Trulli">',
 '<img src="images/dice3.png" alt="Italian Trulli">',
 '<img src="images/dice4.png" alt="Italian Trulli">',
 '<img src="images/dice5.png" alt="Italian Trulli">',
 '<img src="images/dice6.png" alt="Italian Trulli">'];

 let player2 = ['<img src="images/dice1.png" alt="Italian Trulli">',
 '<img src="images/dice2.png" alt="Italian Trulli">',
 '<img src="images/dice3.png" alt="Italian Trulli">',
 '<img src="images/dice4.png" alt="Italian Trulli">',
 '<img src="images/dice5.png" alt="Italian Trulli">',
 '<img src="images/dice6.png" alt="Italian Trulli">'];

var randPlayer1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * player1.length);
var randPlayer2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * player2.length);

 var diceRolls = player1[randPlayer1] + " " + player2[randPlayer2];

 if (randPlayer1 > randPlayer2) {

    highestDiceRoll = player1;
    winner = "Player 1";
  } else if (randPlayer2 > randPlayer1) {
    highestDiceRoll = player2;
    winner = "Player 2";
  } else {
    winner = "GAME IS A DRAW";
  }

document.write("The winner is "  + winner + "<br />");
   return diceRolls; //return to display dice on page
}

document.write(rollDice());
```

Comment: Thank you so much.